# Angular.js how to apply currency filter to input type=number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is a Plunkr i created: http://plnkr.co/edit/T9nrjP1LePGYwF8C0yBH

I use the currency $filter and format the inputs of `type="text"`.

Now how do i do the same for `input type="number"`?

Angularjs will set the model to undefined if you key in any letters other than a number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: input value is expected to be undefined when it is not a number. angular sets the input as invalid on such states: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

And what do you want to do exactly? Do you want to allow letters in number input?

Comment: I want the currency formatters to be applied when the user keyin the amount via mobile? setting type="number" gives the user a friendly experience...

Comment: input type="number" will pull out the numeric keyboard on mobile devices